# Conversion to SVF fails with TranslationWorker-InternalFailure

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

I'm following the tutorial "[Extract Data from a Source File](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-data-from-source-file/)." I'm able to upload a file as described, but when I try to convert the file to SVF it fails with "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure." I get the same error with both a 3ds file created with Blender and an f3d created with Autodesk Fusion 360.

Here's my code (python):

```
r=requests.post(
    'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job',
    headers={
        'authorization':'{0} {1}'.format(auth_type,auth_token)
    },
    json={
        "input": {
            "urn": urn_cube_base64,
        },
        "output": {
            "formats": [
                {
                    "type": "svf",
                    "views": [
                        "2d",
                        "3d"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
)
print r.json()

while True:
    r=requests.get('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{0}/manifest'.format(urn_cube_base64),
        headers={
            'authorization':'{0} {1}'.format(auth_type,auth_token)
        },
    )
    print r.text
    rj=r.json()
    progress=rj['progress']
    status=rj['status']
    print rj['status'],progress
    if status in ('success','failed','timeout'):
        print json.dumps(rj,indent=2)
        break
```

It produces the following output:

```
{
  "hasThumbnail": "false", 
  "status": "failed", 
  "derivatives": [
    {
      "hasThumbnail": "false", 
      "status": "failed", 
      "name": "LMV Bubble", 
      "messages": [
        {
          "message": "Extractor error code -1073741819", 
          "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure", 
          "type": "error"
        }
      ], 
      "outputType": "svf", 
      "progress": "complete"
    }
  ], 
  "region": "US", 
  "version": "1.0", 
  "progress": "complete", 
  "type": "manifest", 
  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dG1wX2J1Y2tldDEvY3ViZS4zZHM"
}
```

Comment: One reason could be you didn't upload the file correctly so the data is corrupted another reason could be the file itself is corrupted. Can you provide the design file so I can test? Also did you try to drop your file in our online viewer: https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your reply until now. The sha1sum of the file checks out so I don't believe the problem is with the upload. I will try the online viewer.

Comment: I tried uploading the files to the viewer. One, an f3d file created with Autodesk Fusion 360, succeeded. The other was a 3ds file created with Blender; it failed with:

Processing failed

Extractor error code -1073741819

Comment: Here are links to the files: 

File 1: [f3d file (created with Fusion 360)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8nfGIkbNxXfbzAxY1dQZEtoNDg).

File 2: [3ds file (created with Blender)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8nfGIkbNxXfRWt3ZE1sYkplRkU)

Comment: the .3ds is not yet supported by the service. For the .f3d I have no problem uploading and translating that file to SVF, you can give a try in my sample: https://oss.autodesk.io. The source is there (node.js): https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs/tree/project5. Hope that helps.

Comment: For the F3D file, I forgot to change the URN when I checked the status, so I was checking the status of the 3DS file when I thought I was checking the F3D file. Thanks for the info about 3DS not being supported. The documentation says it is but it must be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, incorrect doc, sorry about that. You can use the GET /formats endpoint which should be more accurate: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/formats-GET/